# Flickering screen when drawing multiple textured objects with Vulkan

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am new to Vulkan so please don't smite me into oblivion. I have been building a program which can load 3D models that are in fbx format. I ran into a problem when rendering multiple textured objects at once. I have been building the program based on a book called Learning Vulkan with some minor changes here and there.

EDIT:
I have now moved the rendering function to VulkanRenderer from VulkanDrawable. I gather the drawing command buffers from each VulkanDrawable into a vector and try to submit that to the queue but receive an error and the program crashes after drawing one of the objects to the screen for fraction of a second. Program fails with the following error, which I can't seem to be able to fix: [VK_DEBUG_REPORT] ERROR: [ObjectTracker] Code149:Invalid Command Buffer Object 0x21.
Below are the requested code snippets.

Here is the function (and possibly the bug too) in VulkanRenderer:

```
bool VulkanRenderer::render(){
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glfwPollEvents();

    uint32_t& currentColorImage = swapChainObject->scPublicVariables.currentColorBuffer;
    VkSwapchainKHR& swapchain = swapChainObject->scPublicVariables.swapchain;

    //Get the index of the next available swapchain image
    VkResult result = swapChainObject->fpAcquireNextImageKHR(deviceObject->device,
                                                             swapchain,
                                                             UINT64_MAX,
                                                             presentCompleteSemaphore,
                                                             VK_NULL_HANDLE,
                                                             &currentColorImage);

    //getDrawBuffer function inside VulkanDrawable looks like this (all in header file):
    //inline VkCommandBuffer* getDrawBuffer(int index){return &vecCmdDraw[index];}

    //This is a temporary solution and probably wrong as well. I am gathering pointers to
    //the drawing buffers that I want to execute.
    std::vector<VkCommandBuffer*> buffers{drawableObjects[0]->getDrawBuffer(currentColorImage),
                                          drawableObjects[1]->getDrawBuffer(currentColorImage)};

    //Create submit information
    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = {};
    submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
    submitInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = &presentCompleteSemaphore;
    submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = &submitPipelineStages;
    submitInfo.commandBufferCount = (uint32_t)sizeof(buffers) / sizeof(VkCommandBuffer);
    //This *buffers.data looks dodgy but it won't compile otherwise
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = *buffers.data();
    submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = &drawingCompleteSemaphore;

    CommandBufferManager::submitCommandBuffer(deviceObject->queue, *buffers.data(), &submitInfo);

    //Present image in the window
    VkPresentInfoKHR present = {};
    present.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;
    present.pNext = nullptr;
    present.swapchainCount = 1;
    present.pSwapchains = &swapchain;
    present.pImageIndices = &currentColorImage;
    present.pWaitSemaphores = &drawingCompleteSemaphore;
    present.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    present.pResults = nullptr;

    //queue the image for presentation
    result = swapChainObject->fpQueuePresentKHR(deviceObject->queue, &present);
  }
}
```

Here is the submitCommandBuffer function (fence is VK_NULL_HANDLE as default):

```
//Submits given command buffer to given queue with provided submit info and fence.  
void CommandBufferManager::submitCommandBuffer(const VkQueue &queue,
                                           const VkCommandBuffer *cmdBuffer,
                                           const VkSubmitInfo *submitInfo,
                                           const VkFence &fence){
VkResult result;
//If submit information is provided, use it.
if(submitInfo)
{
    result = vkQueueSubmit(queue, 1, submitInfo, fence);
    assert(!result);

    result = vkQueueWaitIdle(queue);
    assert(!result);
    return;
}

//If not, create default submit info
VkSubmitInfo defaultSubmitInfo = {};
defaultSubmitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
defaultSubmitInfo.pNext = nullptr;
defaultSubmitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 0;
defaultSubmitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = nullptr;
defaultSubmitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 0;
defaultSubmitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = nullptr;
defaultSubmitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = nullptr;
defaultSubmitInfo.commandBufferCount = (uint32_t) sizeof(cmdBuffer) / sizeof(VkCommandBuffer);
defaultSubmitInfo.pCommandBuffers = cmdBuffer;

result = vkQueueSubmit(queue, 1, &defaultSubmitInfo, fence);
assert(!result);

result = vkQueueWaitIdle(queue);
assert(!result);
}
```

Renderpass:

```
void VulkanRenderer::createRenderPass(bool includeDepth, bool clear)
{
//This function depends on the VulkanSwapchain to get the
//color image and VulkanRenderer to get the depth image
VkResult result;

//Attach color and depth buffers as an attachment to render pass instance.
VkAttachmentDescription attachments[2];
attachments[0].format = swapChainObject->scPublicVariables.format;
attachments[0].samples = NUM_SAMPLES;
//If clear is required, use it, else don't care.
attachments[0].loadOp = clear ? VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR : VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachments[0].storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
attachments[0].stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachments[0].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachments[0].initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
attachments[0].finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;
attachments[0].flags = VK_ATTACHMENT_DESCRIPTION_MAY_ALIAS_BIT;

//If depth buffer is presented, define the properties for depth buffer attachment
if(includeDepth)
{
    attachments[1].format = Depth.format;
    attachments[1].samples = NUM_SAMPLES;
    attachments[1].loadOp = clear ? VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR :
                                    VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachments[1].storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    attachments[1].stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD;
    attachments[1].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    attachments[1].initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    attachments[1].finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
    attachments[1].flags = VK_ATTACHMENT_DESCRIPTION_MAY_ALIAS_BIT;
}

//Define color buffer attachment binding points and layout information
VkAttachmentReference colorReference = {};
colorReference.attachment = 0;
colorReference.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

//Define depth buffer attachment binding points and layout information
VkAttachmentReference depthReference = {};
depthReference.attachment = 1;
depthReference.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

//Specify attachments - color, depth, resolve, preserve etc.
VkSubpassDescription subpass = {};
subpass.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
subpass.flags = 0;
subpass.inputAttachmentCount = 0;
subpass.pInputAttachments = nullptr;
subpass.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
subpass.pColorAttachments = &colorReference;
subpass.pResolveAttachments = nullptr;
subpass.pDepthStencilAttachment = includeDepth ? &depthReference : nullptr;
subpass.preserveAttachmentCount = 0;
subpass.pPreserveAttachments = nullptr;

//Specify the attachment and subpass associated with render pass
VkRenderPassCreateInfo createInfo = {};
createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
createInfo.pNext = nullptr;
createInfo.attachmentCount = includeDepth ? 2 : 1;
createInfo.pAttachments = attachments;
createInfo.subpassCount = 1;
createInfo.pSubpasses = &subpass;
createInfo.dependencyCount = 0;
createInfo.pDependencies = nullptr;

//Create the render pass
result = vkCreateRenderPass(deviceObject->device, &createInfo, nullptr, &renderPass);
assert(result == VK_SUCCESS);
}
```

EDIT: forgot to add command buffer recording and parts of the api dump:

```
Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer, pBeginInfo) returns VkResult VK_SUCCESS (0):
    commandBuffer:                  VkCommandBuffer = 0x1fc0bf0
    pBeginInfo:                     const VkCommandBufferBeginInfo* = 0x1f9c070:
        sType:                          VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO (42)
        pNext:                          const void* = NULL
        flags:                          VkCommandBufferUsageFlags = 0
        pInheritanceInfo:               const VkCommandBufferInheritanceInfo* = UNUSED

Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkCmdBeginRenderPass(commandBuffer, pRenderPassBegin, contents) returns void:
    commandBuffer:                  VkCommandBuffer = 0x1fc0bf0
    pRenderPassBegin:               const VkRenderPassBeginInfo* = 0x1fc2810:
        sType:                          VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO (43)
        pNext:                          const void* = NULL
        renderPass:                     VkRenderPass = 0x1f76d00
        framebuffer:                    VkFramebuffer = 0x1f77b00
        renderArea:                     VkRect2D = 0x1fc2830:
            offset:                         VkOffset2D = 0x1fc2830:
                x:                              int32_t = 0
                y:                              int32_t = 0
            extent:                         VkExtent2D = 0x1fc2838:
                width:                          uint32_t = 800
                height:                         uint32_t = 800
        clearValueCount:                uint32_t = 2
        pClearValues:                   const VkClearValue* = 0x1fc2860
            pClearValues[0]:                const VkClearValue = 0x1fc2860 (Union):
                color:                          VkClearColorValue = 0x1fc2860 (Union):
                    float32:                        float[4] = 0x1fc2860
                        float32[0]:                     float = 1
                        float32[1]:                     float = 1
                        float32[2]:                     float = 1
                        float32[3]:                     float = 1
                    int32:                          int32_t[4] = 0x1fc2860
                        int32[0]:                       int32_t = 1065353216
                        int32[1]:                       int32_t = 1065353216
                        int32[2]:                       int32_t = 1065353216
                        int32[3]:                       int32_t = 1065353216
                    uint32:                         uint32_t[4] = 0x1fc2860
                        uint32[0]:                      uint32_t = 1065353216
                        uint32[1]:                      uint32_t = 1065353216
                        uint32[2]:                      uint32_t = 1065353216
                        uint32[3]:                      uint32_t = 1065353216
                depthStencil:                   VkClearDepthStencilValue = 0x1fc2860:
                    depth:                          float = 1
                    stencil:                        uint32_t = 1065353216
            pClearValues[1]:                const VkClearValue = 0x1fc2870 (Union):
                color:                          VkClearColorValue = 0x1fc2870 (Union):
                    float32:                        float[4] = 0x1fc2870
                        float32[0]:                     float = 1
                        float32[1]:                     float = 0
                        float32[2]:                     float = 0
                        float32[3]:                     float = 0
                    int32:                          int32_t[4] = 0x1fc2870
                        int32[0]:                       int32_t = 1065353216
                        int32[1]:                       int32_t = 0
                        int32[2]:                       int32_t = 0
                        int32[3]:                       int32_t = 0
                    uint32:                         uint32_t[4] = 0x1fc2870
                        uint32[0]:                      uint32_t = 1065353216
                        uint32[1]:                      uint32_t = 0
                        uint32[2]:                      uint32_t = 0
                        uint32[3]:                      uint32_t = 0
                depthStencil:                   VkClearDepthStencilValue = 0x1fc2870:
                    depth:                          float = 1
                    stencil:                        uint32_t = 0
    contents:                       VkSubpassContents = VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE (0)

Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffer, pipelineBindPoint, pipeline) returns void:
    commandBuffer:                  VkCommandBuffer = 0x1fc0bf0
    pipelineBindPoint:              VkPipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS (0)
    pipeline:                       VkPipeline = 0x1fa4ae0

Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffer, pipelineBindPoint, layout, firstSet, descriptorSetCount, pDescriptorSets, dynamicOffsetCount, pDynamicOffsets) returns void:
    commandBuffer:                  VkCommandBuffer = 0x1fc0bf0
    pipelineBindPoint:              VkPipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS (0)
    layout:                         VkPipelineLayout = 0x1fa2fe0
    firstSet:                       uint32_t = 0
    descriptorSetCount:             uint32_t = 1
    pDescriptorSets:                const VkDescriptorSet* = 0x1fc2970
        pDescriptorSets[0]:             const VkDescriptorSet = 0x1fa1f70
    dynamicOffsetCount:             uint32_t = 0
    pDynamicOffsets:                const uint32_t* = NULL

Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffer, firstBinding, bindingCount, pBuffers, pOffsets) returns void:
    commandBuffer:                  VkCommandBuffer = 0x1fc0bf0
    firstBinding:                   uint32_t = 0
    bindingCount:                   uint32_t = 1
    pBuffers:                       const VkBuffer* = 0x1fc2a40
        pBuffers[0]:                    const VkBuffer = 0x1f98020
    pOffsets:                       const VkDeviceSize* = 0x7ffc731014c0
        pOffsets[0]:                    const VkDeviceSize = 0

Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkCmdSetViewport(commandBuffer, firstViewport, viewportCount, pViewports) returns void:
    commandBuffer:                  VkCommandBuffer = 0x1fc0bf0
    firstViewport:                  uint32_t = 0
    viewportCount:                  uint32_t = 1
    pViewports:                     const VkViewport* = 0x1f95c58
        pViewports[0]:                  const VkViewport = 0x1f95c58:
            x:                              float = 0
            y:                              float = 0
            width:                          float = 800
            height:                         float = 800
            minDepth:                       float = 0
            maxDepth:                       float = 1

Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkCmdSetScissor(commandBuffer, firstScissor, scissorCount, pScissors) returns void:
    commandBuffer:                  VkCommandBuffer = 0x1fc0bf0
    firstScissor:                   uint32_t = 0
    scissorCount:                   uint32_t = 1
    pScissors:                      const VkRect2D* = 0x1f95c70
        pScissors[0]:                   const VkRect2D = 0x1f95c70:
            offset:                         VkOffset2D = 0x1f95c70:
                x:                              int32_t = 0
                y:                              int32_t = 0
            extent:                         VkExtent2D = 0x1f95c78:
                width:                          uint32_t = 800
                height:                         uint32_t = 800

Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkCmdDraw(commandBuffer, vertexCount, instanceCount, firstVertex, firstInstance) returns void:
    commandBuffer:                  VkCommandBuffer = 0x1fc0bf0
    vertexCount:                    uint32_t = 36
    instanceCount:                  uint32_t = 1
    firstVertex:                    uint32_t = 0
    firstInstance:                  uint32_t = 0

Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkCmdEndRenderPass(commandBuffer) returns void:
    commandBuffer:                  VkCommandBuffer = 0x1fc0bf0

Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer) returns VkResult VK_SUCCESS (0):
    commandBuffer:                  VkCommandBuffer = 0x1fc0bf0

Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkAcquireNextImageKHR(device, swapchain, timeout, semaphore, fence, pImageIndex) returns VkResult VK_SUCCESS (0):
    device:                         VkDevice = 0x1d86dd0
    swapchain:                      VkSwapchainKHR = 0x1f23c60
    timeout:                        uint64_t = 18446744073709551615
    semaphore:                      VkSemaphore = 0x1d8a560
    fence:                          VkFence = 0
    pImageIndex:                    uint32_t* = 0

Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkQueueSubmit(queue, submitCount, pSubmits, fence) returns VkResult VK_SUCCESS (0):
    queue:                          VkQueue = 0x1eba560
    submitCount:                    uint32_t = 1
    pSubmits:                       const VkSubmitInfo* = 0x1efeaa8
        pSubmits[0]:                    const VkSubmitInfo = 0x1efeaa8:
            sType:                          VkStructureType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO (4)
            pNext:                          const void* = NULL
            waitSemaphoreCount:             uint32_t = 1
            pWaitSemaphores:                const VkSemaphore* = 0x1fc3820
                pWaitSemaphores[0]:             const VkSemaphore = 0x1d8a560
            pWaitDstStageMask:              const VkPipelineStageFlags* = 0x1fc3780
                pWaitDstStageMask[0]:           const VkPipelineStageFlags = 1024 (VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT)
            commandBufferCount:             uint32_t = 3
            pCommandBuffers:                const VkCommandBuffer* = 0x1fc3730
                pCommandBuffers[0]:             const VkCommandBuffer = 0x1fa98a0
                pCommandBuffers[1]:             const VkCommandBuffer = 0x1fb01c0
                pCommandBuffers[2]:             const VkCommandBuffer = 0x1fb7d70
            signalSemaphoreCount:           uint32_t = 1
            pSignalSemaphores:              const VkSemaphore* = 0x1fc36e0
                pSignalSemaphores[0]:           const VkSemaphore = 0x1d8a710
    fence:                          VkFence = 0

Thread 0, Frame 0:
vkQueuePresentKHR(queue, pPresentInfo) returns VkResult VK_SUCCESS (0):
    queue:                          VkQueue = 0x1eba560
    pPresentInfo:                   const VkPresentInfoKHR* = 0x1fc2810:
        sType:                          VkStructureType = UNKNOWN (1000001001)
        pNext:                          const void* = NULL
        waitSemaphoreCount:             uint32_t = 1
        pWaitSemaphores:                const VkSemaphore* = 0x1fc36e0
            pWaitSemaphores[0]:             const VkSemaphore = 0x1d8a710
        swapchainCount:                 uint32_t = 1
        pSwapchains:                    const VkSwapchainKHR* = 0x1fc3730
            pSwapchains[0]:                 const VkSwapchainKHR = 0x1f23c60
        pImageIndices:                  const uint32_t* = 0x1d8a418
            pImageIndices[0]:               const uint32_t = 0
        pResults:                       VkResult* = NULL

Thread 0, Frame 1:
vkAcquireNextImageKHR(device, swapchain, timeout, semaphore, fence, pImageIndex) returns VkResult VK_SUCCESS (0):
    device:                         VkDevice = 0x1d86dd0
    swapchain:                      VkSwapchainKHR = 0x1f23c60
    timeout:                        uint64_t = 18446744073709551615
    semaphore:                      VkSemaphore = 0x1d8a560
    fence:                          VkFence = 0
    pImageIndex:                    uint32_t* = 1
[VK_DEBUG_REPORT] ERROR: [ObjectTracker] Code149:Invalid Command Buffer Object 0x21. For more information refer to Vulkan Spec Section '5.4. Command Buffer Submission' which states 'If commandBufferCount is not 0, pCommandBuffers must be a pointer to an array of commandBufferCount valid VkCommandBuffer handles' (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/xhtml/vkspec.html#VkSubmitInfo)
```

Command buffer recording:

```
void VulkanDrawable::recordCommandBuffer(int currentImage, VkCommandBuffer *cmdDraw){

//VulkanDevice* deviceObject = rendererObject->getDevice();

//Specify clear color values
VkClearValue clearValues[2];
clearValues[0].color.float32[0] = 1.0f;
clearValues[0].color.float32[1] = 1.0f;
clearValues[0].color.float32[2] = 1.0f;
clearValues[0].color.float32[3] = 1.0f;

//Specify depth/stencil clear value
clearValues[1].depthStencil.depth = 1.0f;
clearValues[1].depthStencil.stencil = 0;

VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassBegin = {};
renderPassBegin.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
renderPassBegin.pNext = nullptr;
renderPassBegin.renderPass = rendererObject->renderPass;
renderPassBegin.framebuffer = rendererObject->framebuffers[currentImage];
renderPassBegin.renderArea.offset.x = 0;
renderPassBegin.renderArea.offset.y = 0;
renderPassBegin.renderArea.extent.width = rendererObject->width;
renderPassBegin.renderArea.extent.height = rendererObject->height;
renderPassBegin.clearValueCount = 2;
renderPassBegin.pClearValues = clearValues;

//Start recording the render pass instance
vkCmdBeginRenderPass(*cmdDraw, &renderPassBegin, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

//Bind the command buffer with the pipeline
vkCmdBindPipeline(*cmdDraw, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, *pipeline);

//Bind descriptor sets
vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(*cmdDraw, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout,0, 1,
                        descriptorSets.data(),0,nullptr);

//Bind vertex data to the command buffer
const VkDeviceSize offsets[1] = {0};
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(*cmdDraw, 0, 1, &VertexBuffer.buffer, offsets);

//Define the dynamic viewport
initViewports(cmdDraw);

//Define the scissoring also
initScissors(cmdDraw);

//Draw
vkCmdDraw(*cmdDraw, verticeAmount, 1,0,0);
//vkCmdDrawIndexed(*cmdDraw, indiceAmount, 1,0,0,0);

//End render pass instance recording
vkCmdEndRenderPass(*cmdDraw);

}
```

Thanks for your help. If there is any more information you might want to see let me know.

Comment: Moved the rendering function to VulkanRenderer, gathered buffers into an array and submitted them both at once (got two objects at this moment). Got the following error: [VK_DEBUG_REPORT] ERROR: [ObjectTracker] Code149:Invalid Command Buffer Object 0x71. For more information refer to Vulkan Spec Section '5.4. Command Buffer Submission' which states 'If commandBufferCount is not 0, pCommandBuffers must be a pointer to an array of commandBufferCount valid VkCommandBuffer handles' (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/xhtml/vkspec.html#VkSubmitInfo)

Comment: Fixed the problem but now program only draws one object even though there are two buffers being submitted.

Comment: Hello @Zen. You can edit/update your own question instead of appending comments to it. Prefferably describe only the current state, before we get lost in the details of what you did and didn't do.

Comment: PS: Your proposed fix sounds fine. Show that code and describe how it fails. I probably need to see the command buffers and render passes too. Providing api dump (done by enabling similarly named Layer) might be nice.

Comment: Hey @krOoze. I have now added the code snippets that you requested. Right before the crash the vkQueuePresentKHR seems to receive a structure with sType UNKNOWN. The error message pretty clearly says that the command buffer is invalid but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: The `sType` is fine. The `api_dump` just does not know the enum value (yet) for some reason.

Comment: From the log I clearly see you are submitting different Command Buffers than those recorded. That looks like some trivial C++ error with handling variables. The `sizeof( cmdBuffer )`, which is a pointer, specifically raises a red flag for me.